# Open file in current instance of Visual Studio 2022 from integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio, command-line-interface, windows-subsystem-for-linux, devenv

I'm trying to find a command I can use to open a file from the terminal in VS2022 Professional. I'm currently using the integrated Ubuntu terminal from WSL, if that matters. I've tried creating a function in my .bashrc that passes the desired file as an argument to devenv.exe but this always opens a new instance, which is not what I'm looking for. Maybe I just need to provide some options to devenv.exe, but I'm not seeing any info about this. Is there some Windows utility or command that I can use to open a file in the instance that owns the terminal I'm using? Thanks!